# Xamarin Forms iOS app fails to install via MDM (but works fine with Free Provisioning)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017, mdm

I am having problems in deploying a company-specific (i.e. non-public) app that I have created.

The app itself, is a Xamarin Forms sample app, that I have downloaded from Xamarin and have customized it for my purposes inside of Visual Studio 2017 on my PC.

With this, I can build and debug the app on my iPhone, iPad, and iPod Touch, all using the Free Provisioning method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=windows), through my connected MacBook Pro.  (All good so far!)

My Apple account is part of our company's Apple Enterprise account and have followed all instructions online (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/in-house-distribution?tabs=windows) about creating an Adhoc distribution certificate to (in theory) sign the app when creating the output .IPA file; I need the .IPA file as the aim is to use an MDM tool we use (Cisco Meraki) to push out to targeted company iOS devices.

The certificates that I have set-up in the Apple Developer website all appear in Visual Studio, and have them selected in my Release configuration for the app, as instructed (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=windows).

The output .IPA file appears to be created successfully, and I can upload it to Meraki as per their instructions... but when the app appears on the device, the install seems to stop, the icon is heavily darkened and the app is just a useless icon on the device.

I have tried other configurations of build config in VS2017, multiple other devices, and have even tried to use Apple's MDM tool (Configurator 2) but I get pretty much the same result.

Am I missing something? Is there an option inside of Visual Studio 2017 that I need to toggle to allow the output app to actually work?

Comment: Can you publish an Ad-hoc-based / Release build IPA to your local device and have it work successfully? (i.e. Are you testing release build IPAs and not just debug versions before publishing via MDM?)

Comment: @SushiHangover - Negative - changing to the Release build and pushing via VS2017 > MBP > Device doesn't work.  ALSO, getting the Debug version to create an IPA file and getting that pushed through to Meraki / Configurator2 *doesn't* work either...
Am thinking it's certificate-related... All very confusing and not at all straight forward. :-(

Comment: There is no debug build IPA. If you can not run an adhoc developer based IPA in the device, the cert is not the problem, what output do you get from the device log?

Comment: If deploying a release build app via VS results in an app that does not run, not a cert issue, what does the device output have in it, assuming it is an issue related to let linking since it sounds like you have never tested a release config build.

Comment: @SushiHangover - apologies - might have confused me with my poor terminology...  I haven't got any Adhoc build configurations, but presume you're meaning Release.  I now have it such that I can change to Release config, and 'Start without Debugging', and my iDevice runs the app just fine.  (Does that help to explain things from my side?)

Comment: When you install it and it doesn't work, does it give you an error? You should connect your device to your mac and watch the console logs when installing it. They usually give some clue to the error when failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out that I didn't actually sign up for the correct Apple account initially, and this is the basis of all my problems.

I signed up to the **Apple Developer Account**, which allows you to create apps for use in the App Store, but not for use with an MDM tool, like Cisco Meraki or Apple Configurator2.  This account is $79/year.

What I ***should*** have signed up for, was the **Apple ENTERPRISE Account**, which *does* allow for the publication of house to devices via an MDM tool, but does not permit publication to the App Store. This account is $299/year.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Ad-Hoc profiles when releasing via MDM. Ad-Hoc requires the UDID of every device to be in the profile. That means that you'd have to collect that information from every possible device and add it to the developer portal *before* signing the app. You also have a device limit using this method. Use a Production certificate and In House Distribution provisioning profile to sign it.
The only downside is that every user will have to "Trust" the enterprise developer for the first run only to be able to open the app.